# Presentation of Product Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-groups, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

Here is the question I have been working on:

If $G_1 = \langle X_1 : R_1\rangle$ and $G_2 = \langle X_2 : R_2\rangle$, supply a presentation for $G_1 \times G_2$.
Deduce that, if $G_1$ and $G_2$ are finitely presented, then so is $G_1 \times G_2$.

Notation: $G_1$ is defined to be $F(X)/\langle R_1\rangle$,
where $ \langle R_1\rangle $ is the normal subgroup generated by $R_1$

I am unsure how to approach this - I know any element of $\langle R_1 \rangle$ is of the form
$$\prod w_i r_i ^{e_i}w_i^{-1},$$
where $w_i \in F(X_1)$, and $r_i \in R_1$, and $e_i = \pm 1$ for all $i$.

Comment: Just combine their generating sets together and their relations together, but add extra relations saying each generator from the first set commutes with each generator from the second.

Comment: First yourself: What's a good generating set for $G_1 \times G_2$? Next ask yourself: What important relators are there mixing together generators of $G_1$ and $G_2$?